# UserDefault should not remove only one key

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I want to remove all object in userdefaults. while hitting the logout button. expect one bool key should not remove.May i know its possible

```
func resetUserDefaults() {

    print("userDefaults successfully removed from the app")

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let dict = userDefaults.dictionaryRepresentation()

    dict.keys.forEach { key in        
       userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer:

```swift
for key in dict.keys where key != "YouBoolKey" {
    userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's add condition like this

```
 dict.keys.forEach { key in 
        if key != "YouBoolKey" {
            userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
 }
```

And dont forget to synchronize at the end

```
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: You don't need to call [synchronize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize) any more

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is, just put the login data in one Object (Structure), save that to UserDefaults and remove that while pressing the logout button.

You may refer the [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-load-and-save-a-struct-in-userdefaults-using-codable).

Answer (score 0):

see my way at:
[How to remove all data by a suite name from UserDefaults in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602607/how-to-remove-all-data-by-a-suite-name-from-userdefaults-in-swift/59917261#59917261)

in wipe data.
You can also use a for... on your array of KEYS.